# How to create a simple user log-in

Tags: python-3.x, authentication

I am reading a book about Python programming, which suggested that I try to create a simple log-in so I wrote:

```
name='Simon'
password='SimonZmugg'

print('please type your username')
Username=input()

if name=='Simon':
    print('Hello Simon')
else:
    print('Oh we donţ know you do you want to create a new account?')

print('type your password')
Password=input()
if Password=='SimonZmugg':
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('wrong password')
```

While printing out "wrong password" if it is entered incorrectly, it doesn't print the `else` statement.

I tried to correct the indentation but I guess everything is correct for that matter.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO!! Which else statement do you mean? Could you give an example output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with the code.

First, you need to keep track of which variable is which. You run `Username=input()` but then never check `Username` again. Your first if statement is `if name=='Simon'` but `name` is hard-coded as "Simon". As such, no matter what username you provide, it will print 'Hello Simon'. The first if statement should be `if name == Username:`

There is nothing wrong with your second if/else statement as posted, but the problem you are probably having is getting the `Password` and `password` variables mixed up. Never create variable names that differ only in case, it will cause confusion.

All fixed, this gives:

```
name = 'Simon'
password = 'SimonZmugg'

print('please type your username')
nameinput = input()

if name == nameinput:
    print('Hello Simon')
else:
    print('Oh we donţ know you do you want to create a new account?')

print('type your password')
passwordinput = input()
if password == passwordinput:
    print('Access granted')
else:
    print('wrong password')
```